# У меня почему то в Chrome все шрифты немного меньше чем в firefox или IE

Tags: google-chrome, firefox

Windows 10 OS  заметил что в Crome все мелкое, хотя все настройки и масштаб стоит по умолчанию.
Можно ли это как то исправить?
Грешу на винду. Что шрифты отличаются видно даже на скриншотах.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На мониторах с высоким DPI Edge и IE автоматически выставляют масштаб страницы больше. Т.е. Масштаб по-умолчанию может быть 125%, 150%, и т.д.

Хром, Яндекс браузер, этого не делают. За ФФ не скажу.

Comment: Похоже на то, сравнил при 125% в Crome и IE  почти одинаково 
http://prntscr.com/86s9vm

Comment: @korolariya Это легко проверить. В IE в настройках будет Zoom(125%), а в раскрывающемся меню будет Ctrl+0 около 125%.